# prove a trigonometric polynomial has no more than $2n$ disctinct roots in $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Prove the nonzero polynomial $$T(\theta)=a_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(a_k\cos
> k\theta+b_k\sin k\theta)$$  has no more than $2n$ distinct roots on
> $[0,2\pi).$

My attempt:
From $\cos k\theta=\dfrac{e^{ik\theta}+e^{-ik\theta}}{2}$ and $\sin k\theta=\dfrac{e^{ik\theta}-e^{-ik\theta}}{2i}$, $T$ can be rewritten as $T(\theta)=e^{-ni\theta}p(e^{i\theta})$, with $p$ is a polynomial, $degp\leq 2n$.
$\Rightarrow T(\theta)=0\iff e^{-ni\theta}p(e^{i\theta})=0\iff p(e^{i\theta})=0$
I know that $p(z)=0$ has no more than $2n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$, but how can I argue that $p(e^{i\theta})=0$ also has no more than $2n$ roots in $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: You are essentially done. If $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_k$ are distinct roots of $T(\theta)$ in $[0, 2 \pi)$ then $z_1 = e^{i \theta_1}, \ldots, z_k = e^{i \theta_k}$ are distinct roots of $p(z)$ in $\Bbb C$, therefore $k \le 2n$.

Comment: What if $a_k=b_k=0$ for all $k$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ be a root of $T$, so that $T(\theta)=0$. Then you have found that $p(e^{i\theta})=0$ for some (nonzero?) polynomial $p$ of degree at most $2n$. This means $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of $p$. Of course the map
$$[0,2\pi)\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ \theta\ \longmapsto\ e^{i\theta},$$
is injective. So if $T$ has more than $2n$ roots in $[0,2\pi)$, then also $p$ has more than $2n$ roots in $\Bbb{C}$, a contradiction.